# Protocol to communicate between Python and Unity?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, networking

I want my Python scripts to communicate with Unity. Any recommendations on how to do it? Socket, HTTP? They are running on the same computer.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too broad - what platforms are you targeting in Unity? Is it a realtime or turn based game? What sort of traffic are you expecting, and do you want something quick or something well made? E.g. if you want to target the web, and it's a realtime multiplayer, then the option there is websockets. If it's turn based and you want something quick, then a json API is fine. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

[Python for Unity Editor](https://forum.unity.com/threads/introducing-python-for-unity-editor.812748/) now available as a preview package.